# What is the range of addresses for J and JAL instructions when PC=0x8FFFEE4F

Tags: assembly, mips

How can I calculate the range?

I know that `j` and `jal` target is anywhere within a block of `2^28` addresses where PC supplies the upper 4 bits but I couldn't implement it.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple. You take the 4 upper bits of PC+4, and append the 26-bit immediate operand of `J` or `JAL` multiplied by 4 (so you can only jump at addresses that are multiple of 4).

For `PC=0x8FFFEE4F`, the 4 upper bits of `PC+4` are `0x8`, so you can jumps anywhere from `0x80000000` to `0x8FFFFFFC`. If the operand is 0x3FFF404, the operation is `J 0x8FFFD010` ( `0x8 : 0x3FFF404*4` = `0x8 : 0xFFFD010` )

The `PC+4` doesn't matter in most case, but it means that if `PC=0x8FFFFFFC`, the range will be `0x90000000` to `0x9FFFFFFC`.